# Image not showing in webapp maven project in eclipse oxyegen?

Tags: html, css, eclipse, twitter-bootstrap, maven

I have a simple code snippet to show two buttons and an image, but it's only showing the buttons and a alt part of the `<img>` tag.
    It does show the image when the whole address is given.

Where should I store the image?
I have tried in:

- Project main folder (/Shopping)
- /Shopping/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/bootstrap
- /Shopping/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
- /Shopping/src

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CDN, normally stored on webserver -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <input type="search">
      <input type="submit" value="search">
      <button class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
      <img border="0" src="images\logo.png" alt="logo" width="304" height="228" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) on HTML File Paths.

You're now referring to  an image that is located in `/images`, a subdirectory of the folder in which your html-page is saved. If there is no such directory then the image will not be displayed.

So if your webpage is stored in `https://yourdomain.com/index.html`, then your image should be stored in `https://yourdomain.com/images/logo.png`.

Please keep in mind that you should use a *forward slash* `/`, instead of a *backward slash* `\` when defining an images location.